# How to convert results from Combinatorics

Tags: type-conversion, julia, combinatorics

Using Julia 1.0.1, I want to obtain a vector of all combinations of 5 objects, the objects being the [1,2], and each of the number 3,4,5 and 6

I have created an object `a  = [[1,2],3,4,5,6]` and obtained the combinations.

```
using Combinatorics
a  = [[1,2],3,4,5,6]
anas5 = collect(combinations(a))
```

As expected, I am obtaining

```
31-element Array{Array{Any,1},1}:

 [[1, 2]]            
 [3]                 
 [4]                 
 [5]                 
 [6]                 
 [[1, 2], 3] 
...
```

How can I transform the results so that the combinations including [1, 2]  become a vector. 
For example, so the first few lines described above become:

```
 [1, 2]            
 [3]                 
 [4]                 
 [5]                 
 [6]                 
 [1, 2, 3] 
...
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Iterators.flatten` to flatten your Vector of Vectors.

`collect.(Iterators.flatten.(anas5))`